# Update field if text changed AND has focus

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, textwatcher

I am trying to implement an activity which converts units. There are five fields which I want to be able to convert between on the fly. I can't simply use `TextWatcher` because when I change a field then that changes all the other fields and cause a circular call which crashes.

I looked at `OnFocusChangeListener` but that only works when the focus changes whereas I want the update to occur on the fly.

I then thought I could combine the two so I have my `TextWatcher` and inside that I put this

```
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            if (convert_kg.hasfocus())
                {
                if (convert_kg.getText().toString().matches("")) sums=0.0;  
                else sums=Double.parseDouble(convert_kg.getText().toString());

                answer=(int)Math.round(sums*2.205);
                convert_lbs.setText(String.format("%d", answer));
                    }
         }
```

but I am getting an error of **The method hasfocus() is undefined for the type EditText**

These are my imports:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
```

As far as I can tell from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html it should be supported? I'm sure this is simple but any ideas?

EDIT: In case anyone was wondering all the fields are EditText

```
convert_kg=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.convert_kg);
```

Comment: You have to attach a TextWatcher when a Field is focused.

Comment: try using isFocused() instead of hasfocus().

Comment: isFocussed() is what I needed. Thanks krishna you are a legend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the comments. isFocused() was the method I needed to use.